# Javascript Variable Declaration: this versus var

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, this

Is there a difference between

```
function test(){
    var myVar;
}
```

and

```
function test(){
    this.myVar;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is determined by how function is called whereas `var VARIABLE_NAME` will create a variable in the `local-scope` of the function.

In second example, you are creating `Object-Constructor` using which you can create many instances of the `test` object using [`new operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

```js
function test(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
console.log(new test('Abc'));
console.log(new test('Xyz'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two scopes in javascript , `local or function scope` and `global scope` . 
In your case `this is global` and `var is local scope/function scope` .

If you use `this` inside IIFE (immediate invoking function expression)and 'use strict' its not global

Answer (score 0):

The most difference is that your first code works like a private property (local scope) and the second is like a public property (global scope).

### Examples:

```js
var test = function(){
  this.myVar = "test var";
}

var test2 = function() {
  var myVar = "test2 var"; 
}

alert((new test()).myVar);
alert((new test2()).myVar);
```

Comment: Explain the downvote. Always the same, if you don't explain nobody can know why this is incorrect

Comment: You are welcome, I am waiting for the person that downvote this, even is correct (working example makes sense). Good luck :)

Comment: Its SO, you have to have thick skin to withstand haters. Sad but true

Comment: You make me laugh! Thank you sir :)